# How to remove quotations and then inner brackets from a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
["['mnmd']",
 "['iphones']",
 "['aapl']",
 "['apple']",
 "['gme']",
 "['aapl']",
 "['msft']",
 "['']",
 "['yolo']"]
```

Is there any simple pythonic way to remove the outer quotations and then the inner brackets?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip will help

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> x = ["['mnmd']",
...  "['iphones']",
...  "['aapl']",
...  "['apple']",
...  "['gme']",
...  "['aapl']",
...  "['msft']",
...  "['']",
...  "['yolo']"]
>>> x
["['mnmd']", "['iphones']", "['aapl']", "['apple']", "['gme']", "['aapl']", "['msft']", "['']", "['yolo']"]
>>> [item for s in x for item in ast.literal_eval(s)]
['mnmd', 'iphones', 'aapl', 'apple', 'gme', 'aapl', 'msft', '', 'yolo']
```

or

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(ast.literal_eval, x)))
['mnmd', 'iphones', 'aapl', 'apple', 'gme', 'aapl', 'msft', '', 'yolo']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combinatio of [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) functions on string passed in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
sample_list = ["['mnmd']",
               "['iphones']",
               "['aapl']",
               "['apple']",
               "['gme']",
               "['aapl']",
               "['msft']",
               "['']",
               "['yolo']"]

outlist = [eval(entry.strip("[]")) for entry in sample_list]
>>> outlist
['mnmd', 'iphones', 'aapl', 'apple', 'gme', 'aapl', 'msft', '', 'yolo']
```